# View process work from method in custom class

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Alert: bad English :)

I want to display 2+ messages on web-page from a custom class - `Exp(object)`, which contains method `do_this()`, which do some steps - 1 and 2. I want to display result of this steps, for example, step 1 return string 'creating object...' and 2 step return string 'wait for update'. This steps i can break to 2 methods - `do_this_1()` and `do_this_2()` for example.

```
if 'create' in request.POST:
    Exp().do_this()
```

before `request.POST`, page was created, so we can use ajax, but i dont know how to do this in custom class

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you can return messages like this:

```
class Exp(object):
    def do_this(self):
        messages = {}
        messages['step1']=self.do_this1()
        messages['step2']=self.do_this2()
        return messages

if 'create' in request.POST:
    messages = Exp().do_this()
    messages_json = simplejson.dumps(messages)
    return http.HttpResponse(messages_json, mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: I want to return messages two times, after complit do_this1() and after do this2() :(

Comment: Then you should store your steps messages somewhere and request them through ajax using setTimeout or look at socket.io.